# Magento 2 - set cash on delivery not accepted to specific countries and states

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

I want  **no COD** is accepted in Saudi except for City of Jeddah with COD fees SR 20/shipment/AWB. COD in UAE is OK with no additional charges.
I'm using magento 2. Can anyone help?